# Сервер для браузерной игры

Tags: сервер

Здравствуйте! Написал браузерную игру для телефона, игра храниться на локальном сервере, подскажите что нужно выбрать для того, чтобы было комфортно играть выйдя в сеть. Сервер, хостинг и т.п? Что из этого? PS бюджет 1т.р:)

Comment: игра многопользовательская? если да - на чем написан сервер?

Comment: на PHP написан

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) - в рамках их бесплатной квоты вполне развернётесь. Если игра станет популярной, придётся раскошелиться на 1 т. р. : )